# ffmpeg failed - 455 Method Not Valid in This State

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, docker, streaming, rtsp

I created a `nodejs` app that gets an `rtsp` streaming with `FFMPEG` to analyse it with `Opencv3`. It is working if I install `FFMPEG` and `opencv` in my local.

But now I created a docker image that contains the installation of those libraries and I'm using it as a base to create another image & container where I'm trying to run my app. When I run it inside that container I get this error over and over again when trying to get the `rtsp` stream with an `FFMPEG` instruction for ***"method SETUP failed: 455 Method Not Valid in This State"***.

This is how I am installing FFMPEG in the image:

```
# ---------------------- OpenCV ffmpeg ---------------------------#
RUN mkdir -p /opt/src \
 && curl -Lo /opt/src/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
  && tar -xvf /opt/src/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz -C /opt/src \
  && cd /opt/src/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} \
  && ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
  --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-version3 \
  --enable-shared --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie \
  && make -j $(nproc) \
  && make install \
  && ldconfig -v \
  && rm -rf /opt/src

# ---------------------- OpenCV stuff ---------------------------#
RUN mkdir -p /opt/src/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build \
  && curl -sLo /opt/src/opencv3.tar.gz \
     https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzvf /opt/src/opencv3.tar.gz -C /opt/src \
  && cd /opt/src/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build \
  && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON .. \
  && make -j "$(nproc)" \
  && make install \
  && ldconfig -v \
  && rm -rf /opt/src
```

Do you have any idea what this error is and how to fix it? I think it might have to do with the initial configuration on the installation of either of them (`FFMPEG` or `OPENCV`).

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're probably going to have to do some trial and error. Remove the `--enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
  --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-version3 \
  --enable-shared --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie` one at a time, recompiling after each removed switch. This test, although tedious will tell you if one of your enables is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks @cube. The problem i'm having now is tht I need to enable tcp as transport method. Eny idea of how I can do that with the enables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a fix in the new version of OpenCV released recently (Opencv3.1) that takes in consideration tcp transport, so by upgrading to the newest I managed to fix the problem